# Change variable but keep it saved?

Tags: java

I have a lot of things which I want to display in the GUI. So I put them all in an array. I run a for loop which adds them onto the screen one by one.

```
for(int num = 0; num<MYARRAY.length; num++){

        addToGui(MYARRAY[num], xCoords, yCoords);

    }
```

All the code works, but the coordinates are the same for everything I add, so everything overlaps on the screen. I tried

```
for(int num = 0; num<MYARRAY.length; num++){

        addToGui(MYARRAY[num], xCoords, yCoords);
        xCoords += 5;
    }
```

But everything on the screen just moves 5 pixels. So if xCoords = 5, I want to add something to the GUI with xCoords = 5, then add another thing to the screen with xCoords = 10 and so on. How would I do it?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, and to avoid the overlapping, I think this: `addToGui(MYARRAY[0], xCoords, yCoords);` could be changed to `addToGui(MYARRAY[num], (num * xCoords), (num*yCoords));` - keep in mind that xCoords, and yCoords should be > 0 for this to work ;)

Comment: Well, in your for xCoords already increment +5 for every num. What is the problem? You want to keep the old xCoords value even if I recall the method?

Comment: +Marco Acierno, Yea, I want to save the old xCoords value to one thing, then add five to it for the next

Comment: Odds are that xCoords & yCoords are static.

Comment: New problem now, the things I add to the screen fly across the screen

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int num = 0; num<MYARRAY.length; num++){

        addToGui(MYARRAY[num], xCoords, yCoords);
        xCoords += 5;
    }
```

might this help?  You are adding MYARRAY[0] everytime.

Comment: I already had that, I just accidentally posted the wrong code :P

Comment: And that just changes what is drawn, not where it is drawn.